# Changing color dynamically three js not realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

i'm trying to create a 3d configurator

[image]

i wanted to change the color of specific material using colorpicker like this

```
$('#color-block').on('colorchange', function() {
    var newColor = $(this).wheelColorPicker('getValue', 'rgb');
    setColor(\'' + newColor + '\');
})
```

and my `setcolor` function like this

```
function setColor(color) {
    update_svg('color', color);
}

function update_svg(op, value) {
    if (op == 'color') {
        document.getElementById(selectedMaterial).setAttribute("fill", value);
    }
    if (op == 'ftext') {
        document.getElementById(selectedText).innerHTML = value;
    }
    if (op == 'ff') {
        document.getElementById(selectedText).setAttribute('font-family', value);
        document.getElementById(selectedText).style.fontFamily = value;
    }
    if (op == 'fs') {
        document.getElementById(selectedText).style.fontSize = value;
    }

    //PLS SEE THIS
    set_materials(function (resp) {
        obj = object.children[0]?.material;
        obj += textureMaterial;
        render();
    });
}
```

But no matter which color i pick, the 3d object color is not changing in realtime, if i change the color before the 3d object fully loaded, the color change. i give u a not `PLS SEE THIS` that code i changed from

```
set_materials(function (resp) {
        object.children[0].material = textureMaterial;
        render();
    });
```

but that code gives me an error of

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'material' of undefined`

thats why i added `?`, so anyone have any idea why? this is my first time using three js

EDIT

I created stackblitz so u can see what i'm trying to say

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-sqdsoq?file=javascript%2Fmain_s.js

u can check at `openColorPicker` function i think the problem is there

Answer (score 0):

```
material.needsUpdate = true
```

...will next render the supplied color value in the animation loop, assuming that the color is set in a supported format.

It is preferable to select the object (or its children) by traversing the scene's (or group's) descendents with getObjectByName()... ([or a similar accessor]). There is no guarantee that the [0] array index exists, or is the intended object.

Comment: where should i add `material.needsUpdate` ?

Comment: sequentially, following the update or tangentially in a callback

Comment: i dont know what happen, i only remove`?` then it is working LoL, thanks btw